# Is mxml natively supported by flash?

Tags: flash, mxml

I'm now using the cairngorm flex framework,and it supports mxml .

Is this supported natively by flash or only supported by frameworks?

Comment: mxml is supported by flex sdk, however it has to be translated to as3 before compilation. not sure if i understand your question correctly

Comment: So not natively supported by flash itself?

Answer (score 2):

No, MXML is not natively supported in Flash. The Flex SDK includes a compiler, mxmlc.exe, which converts MXML into ActionScript classes. Adobe Flash CS* does not include this compiler, nor does it contain many of the ActionScript classes that MXML gets converted to.